# Apply conditional to output of a commandlet

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements, commandlet

I want to output the result of the commandlet (Invoke-Command) on success and add a custom message if the result is null. The code as shown below produces the desired results except in the event of a null response, it simply outputs nothing on that line.

I can not pipe directly to an if statement, nor can I output on 2 opposing conditions (True & False). Is it possible to get a custom response on $null while not suppressing the normal output on success?

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC1, PC2, PC3 -Scriptblock {get-eventlog system | where-object {$_.eventid -eq 129}  | select MachineName, EventID, TimeGenerated, Message  -last 1}`

If you run the example code block assuming that PC1 and PC3 have the event ID but PC2 does not, the output will simply skip PC2.

I want to output something like "Event Not found" in that case.

Placing the entire thing in a loop and then running the results through another conditional loops destroys performance so that is not an ideal solution.

Comment: when you get the output of your `Invoke-Command` call, the objects SHOULD have a PSComputer property added by the I-C call. you can then compare that with the input list to generate a "not found" message.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: the computer will not appear in the output of `Invoke-Command` because there was nothing to return. For example if you execute `Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'PC1', 'PC2' -ScriptBlock {} #Do nothing inside ScriptBlock` you won't receive an output.

Comment: @Patrick - please, re-read my comment. [*grin*] "you can then compare that with the input list ..."

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: true, sorry :-)

Comment: @Patrick - no problem ... it can be easy to misread ... [*grin*]

Comment: So when invoke command skips over a PC that didnt have hte log entry, you are saying its not actually returning a null value I can apply logic too?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new object for returning from `Invoke-Command`. So you are sure you will receive from every host something even the event log is not present. And might you can change `get-eventlog` to `Get-WinEvent`. `Get-WinEvent` was for my tasks the most time faster than `get-eventlog`.

```
[System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]$Scriptblock = {
    [System.Collections.Hashtable]$Hashtable = @{
        WinEvent = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = 'System'; Id = 129 } -MaxEvents 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue #-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue --> otherwise there is an error if no event is available
    }

    return (New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $Hashtable)
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'PC1', 'PC2', 'PC3' -Scriptblock $Scriptblock
```